# How to get a current font for GtkTextView?

Tags: gtk

It's pretty easy to set the default font for a GtkTextView via `gtk_widget_modify_font()`, but how to **get** which one is current? (I'm not using any tags in the widget.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `gtk_widget_get_style()` to get the current GtkStyle, and then use `gtk_style_get_font()`.